# Return first matching row

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

Sorry if this is a basic question, but I am just a beginner with SQL. I have 2 tables:

1. Table `ACCT_GUID_REF` has 2 fields: an acct number (`ACCTNBR`) and a GUID (`AcctIDGUID`) for that account number.
2. Table `RESTAURANTS` has new details rows for each restaurant.

When I add new rows, I want to update the `RESTAURANTS.ACCT_GUID` column with the matching account in table `ACCT_GUID_REF`.

I tried this, but it returns more than one row since there are multiple restaurant account rows in table `RESTAURANT`.  How can I fix the UPDATE?

```
UPDATE RESTAURANTS
SET RESTAURANTS.ACCT_GUID =
(SELECT AcctIDGUID 
    FROM ACCT_GUID_REF
    WHERE ACCT_GUID_REF.ACCTNBR = RESTAURANTS.ACCTNBR)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may want to do an INNER JOIN in the UPDATE statement's source.

```
UPDATE RESTAURANTS
   SET ACCT_GUID = A.AcctIDGuid
  FROM ACCT_GUID_REF A
       INNER JOIN RESTAURANTS R
               ON A.ACCTNBR = R.ACCTNBR
```